# Why a compiler understand a variable as a pointer while it is not?

Tags: c, function, pointers, variables

I am trying to write this program:

Write a function `digit(n, k)` that returns the *kth* digit (from the right) in n (a positive integer). For example

- `digit(829, 1)` returns 9
- `digit(829, 2)` returns 2
- `digit(829, 3)` returns 8

If k is greater than the number of digits in n, have the function return 0.

I get a warning message:

> returning (int*)(int,int) from a fuction with return type int makes
>   integer from pointer without a cast

```
int digit(int a,int b);

int main (void){

    int i, c;
    printf("Enter the number");
    printf("Enter the digit you want to check");

    scanf("%d",&i);
    scanf("%d",&c);
    puts("\n");

    printf("%d", digit(i,c));
}

int digit (int a, int b){
    while(b>0)
    {
        int digit = a%10;
        a/=10;
        b--;
    }
    return digit;
}
```

What is illegal about that?

Comment: Be aware that warnings containing _" makes integer from pointer without a cast"_ is alm ost always actually an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With

```
return digit;
```

you return a pointer to the *function* `digit` itself.

The *variable* digit is local inside the loop only.

You probably meant to have this variable be outside the loop, but then you should rename it to not confuse it with the function.

Perhaps something like

```
int get_digit(int number, int digit_number)
{
    int one_digit = 0;

    while(digit_number-- > 0)
    {
        one_digit = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }

    return one_digit;
}
```

Note that I have changed the names of all symbols, hopefully they make much more sense now when their names describe what they are for.

Comment: OK, i understood that. But i want to ask a further question if you dont mind: Why can't compiler understand i am referring to variable, because compilers sometimes can run with "common sense" like in the : `int func (int n, int m[*]);`  example.

Comment: Because there's no variable for you to refer to at that point. The only thing named `digit` at the time of the `return digit` statement is the function. The variable `digit` ceased to exist when its scope closed with the brace on the line preceding the return.